# Check large chunk of values for uniqueness in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, optimization

I need to create promo codes which should be short in length (~ 6 characters). The promo codes have to be unique, so I need to check their uniqueness in database as well. They need to be generated in batches of thousands, so a check in db with every coupon generation is not feasible. I have created a method which first generates the required number of coupons and then check for duplicates using where in(). Having duplicate count of greater than zero, makes it generate the count again.

```
public function generateCoupons($count, $length = 6)
{
    $coupons = [];
    while(count($coupons) < $count) {
        do {
            $coupon = strtoupper(str_random($length));
        } while (in_array($coupon, $coupons));
        $coupons[] = $coupon;
    }

    $existing = Offer::whereIn('coupon', $coupons)->count();
    if ($existing > 0)
        $coupons += $this->generateCoupons($existing, $length);

    return (count($coupons) == 1) ? $coupons[0] : $coupons;
}
```

Need suggestions how to improve upon this? Or if I can have some other way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the promo code is indexed in your DB. This will speed up the search for existing promo codes.

Otherwise, your method is good! you want to check as many codes as possible at once (which you do with the whereIn/count) and only re-generate the codes that were not unique.

Answer (score 1):

Build a table `new_codes` with 1000 candidates.  `PRIMARY KEY(code)`.

```
DELETE new_codes
    FROM new_codes
    LEFT JOIN existing_codes ON existing_codes.code = new_codes.code
    WHERE existing_codes.code IS NOT NULL;
```

That (if I did it right) will very quickly delete the dups.  Now you will have not-quite-1000 'good' codes.

Comment: Thank you @Rick - This way I will have to repeat the new insertions, as after deletion, I need to check how many were deleted and regenerate the same number again recursively?

Comment: I assumed the numbers come from a random number generator, so they are mostly different each time?  Build a 1000-row `INSERT` statement with them before doing the `DELETE`.